# How to get registered device face I'ds parameters in facelock android device?

Tags: android, face-recognition, android-biometric

Can we get registered face I'd parameters or image in our device in  face lock android device with programmatically? Am stuck with this, so if it is possible please mention the code or give some hints about it ?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

No, this is prohibited by the Android [Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/10/android-10-cdd) (CDD). What is your use case?

`[C-2-6] MUST NOT enable third-party applications to distinguish between individual biometric enrollments.`